# Spherical Mean equivalent forms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble understanding the following identity for 2 equivalent forms of the spherical mean:
$$\dfrac{1}{d\omega_dr^{d-1}}\int_{\partial B(x, r)} v(y)do(y)=\dfrac{1}{d\omega_d} \int_{|\xi|=1} v(x+r\xi)do(\xi)$$

From my understanding, the first form is integrated over the boundary, and so points $y\in \mathbb{R^n}$ lie on the boundary of a sphere centred at $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$, of radius $r\in \mathbb{R}$.

The change of variables, $y = x + r\xi$ is meant to represent the point $y$ in terms of only $x$ and $r$, correct?

But I do not understand why this makes the new boundary the unit circle. I also don't understand why the volume measure becomes $do(\xi)$, as well as why the $r$ disappears in the RHS (my guess is because the unit circle has radius $1$). What is so special about changing boundaries to the unit circle?

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$|\xi|=1$ does not denote the unit circle - it denotes the unit sphere, $\partial B(0,1)$,

Both expressions are meant to be averages over spheres.  The first sphere is of radius $r$, the second of radius $1$.  And since surface area in $d$-dimensions is proportional to $r^{d-1}$, that's where that factor comes from.

The map $\xi\mapsto x+r\xi$ takes $\partial B(0,1)$ to $\partial B(x,r)$.

Comment: Thank you! That clarifies things a lot. But now I don't understand why the two expressions would be equal if you're averaging over two spheres of different radii. I'm guessing it has to do with the different integrands, but I am having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: Yes.  Its like integration by substitution: $$\int_0^a f(x) \, dx = a \int_0^1 f(ay) \, dy,$$ except the integral is over $d-1$ dimensional space.

Comment: Or another example to illustrate it:  $$\frac1{2r}\int_{a-r}^{a+r} f(x) \, dx = \frac12 \int_{|\xi|\le 1} f(a+r\xi) \, d\xi .$$